# Effect of screen shape on video quality

Tags: video-quality, 4k

How does the shape of screens (that is, different *"width x height"* values while keeping the same total displaying area) affect the quality for a given optimal viewing distance?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your standard of quality is.  If your standard is maximal retina coverage, then, well, you've got round eyeballs, so a 1:1 aspect ratio would be the "best" rectangular shape.  But they don't make square TVs, let alone circle-shaped ones, which would be "better".  On the other hand, if you watch a lot of television, you'll get the most use out of your pixels with 16:9, which is what most stuff is broadcast in these days. If you watch more movies, then maybe you prefer 2.39:1.  Video games? 16:9.  Flight simulator? Maybe you want something panoramic. The best aspect ratio *for you* is the one that most closely matches the content you plan to consume most often.  And aspect ratio and viewing distance are unrelated; one has no impact on the other.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your question. As it is I would say **nothing**.

Get a 16x9 inches monitor. It measures 16 x 9 inches. Now rotate it 90°. It has the exact same total displaying area but now measures 9 x 16 inches. The "optimal" viewing distance is the same.

---

If you are referring to different aspect ratios, the unit that is important and easier to get is the native **linear** PPI.

Find out the horizontal resolution used and divide it by the horizontal physical measure of the display area.

If your monitor has 1920 x 1080 px, use 1920.
If the monitor measures 21 inches on the horizontal size:
1920/21 = 91.4 PPI. Use that value to compare other monitors.

Comment: Thanks. I really meant **aspect ratio**: is it a third variable (together with display size and viewing distance) into play for the _optimal viewing distance_? Ottherwise, how does it affect the display quality?

Answer (score 1):

For watching movies, screens with a greater width than height are better suited. Now the 16: 9 format is popular. For some video games, high screens are suitable, when the character is visible in full growth.

It’s better to look at large screens from a high distance.